# How to use Laravel Homestead for development

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

I know this might sound really silly, but I'm kinda stuck and need help. I'm trying to use Laravel 5.3 and use Homestead as my IDE. I have previously worked on PHP using NetBeans and XAMPP, but the installation has always been a pain. I have no formal training and have learnt and used basic PHP on my own for my webpages.

I'm running a Windows 8-32Bit OS & here's what I've done so far:

- I have downloaded Laravel using Composer.
- I have installed Virtual Box & Vagrant.
- I have installed Git Bash and ran `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` (Homestead.yaml was not found in my Homestead folder after running `bash init.sh` command. I downloaded it from Github and added there).
- Set SSH Key.
- Ran `vagrant up` in Homestead folder (the installation was complete).

**Issues:**

- If I just type `http://localhost:8000` in my browser, nothing happens. I have to run `php artisan serve` in the command prompt inside laravel directory and keep the prompt window open for the default Laravel 5 page to open.
- If I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in my browser, nothing happens at all.

So how do I use Homestead then for my development everyday ?

Comment: Notice that homestead is just your environment. You still need an IDE or text editor to work with Laravel.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the best IDE to speed up the development process with Laravel !!! I know this is out of the scope, but I'm feeling really helpless...

Comment: Everything I suggest you would be only my personal opinion. I use PHPStorm, but it's a paid IDE. You can use Eclipse or Netbeans, which are free. Some people just like sublime or notepad++ (if windows). Some people use Atom. You can try them all and choose what the best fit for you.

Comment: Okay then, I'll stick to NetBeans. Thanks a lot Mr Okano

Answer (score 0):

you can try

localhost/project-name/public

if you dont want to run php artisan serve